# Change the image resolution to 300 dpi

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

Is there any way to change the resolution of an image in the Windows Phone 8 ?. Actually i need to change the image dpi to 300 dpi. I actually have that image inside of my application. In WPF we have the following way.

```
Bitmap b=new Bitmap(Image)
b.SetResolution(xxx,yyy)
```

Is it possible to achieve the same in Windows Phone 8 ?

Comment: No, that's the Winforms way.  Changing the dpi is very unusual, it should only be set by an app that captured the image.  You can always draw an image to whatever size you want, regardless of dpi.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in the Windows Phone 8 to change the resolution of an image stream through PictureDecoder. Input should be

1. Stream.
2. Width and Height for the resolution.

   PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(jpgstream, 1200, 480);

For more information you can look at the below link.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swick/archive/2011/04/07/image-tips-for-windows-phone-7.aspx

Comment: Finally it also helped me..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921003/setting-image-dpi-in-relation-to-height-width-c-sharp